# Using WebSecurity with .Net winForms application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to implement the `WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity()` method in a `.Net` desktop application, the application will connect to a database on the server together with a `MVC4` project so I would like to use the current provider on both applications to authenticate a user.

I was wondering if this is possible as I am getting the exception:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: To call this method, the 
"Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of 
"ExtendedMembershipProvider".
 at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.VerifyProvider()
```

I have copied the `Web.Config` of my `MVC4` application into my `app.config` file but I still cannot seem to get it to work. Any direction would be appreciated

**Edit**
It is something to do with the [InitializeSimpleMembership] attribute that sits on an MVC4 Controller. This performs some Initialisation for WebSecurity. Can anyone see how to initialise this code without it being an attribute?

Thanks again

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to implement the WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity() method in
>   a .Net desktop application

Forget about it. The Membership provider is tightly coupled with the ASP.NET context and not intended to be used in desktop applications. It depends on things like HttpContext, cookies, ... which do not exist in a desktop application.

What you could do instead is to define a reusable service layer that you could use in your desktop application directly and then have an implementation of an ASP.NET membership provider calling the methods of this service layer, thus reusing the same functionality between the two.

Comment: OK All I want to do is try and log in with the username and password of a user which exists in the Web database. Do you know how to check a login is valid without using this WebSecurity.Login()?

Comment: You could simply use Entity Framework or even plain ADO.NET to query a relational database and verify whether a username and password are correct in a given table.

Comment: How are the password's hashed in the websecurity method?

Comment: It is using `HMAC SHA256` with a salt. Take a look at the following blog post illustrating the Crypto Helper class used by the provider: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/200/The-SimpleMembershipProvider-Secure-Passwords-And-The-Crypto-Helper As you can see the salt is not stored into the database but is part of the hash (first 16 bytes).

Comment: Thanks Darin, Thanks I will use this to authenticate the user